# nginx multiple proxy_pass to the same domain using different ssl certificates and subdomains

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, proxypass

I need to use headless puppeteer for a domain with multiple users and a certificate for each user.
Nginx's proxy_pass is used to "inject" the client certificate.

I need to be able to access targetdomain.com with 3 different certificates.

My nginx configuration:

server1 name target.mydomain.com proxy_pass targetdomain.com proxy_ssl_certificate 1.crt proxy_ssl_certificate_key 1.pem

server2 name target2.mydomain.com proxy_pass targetdomain.com proxy_ssl_certificate 2.crt proxy_ssl_certificate_key 2.pem

server3 name target3.mydomain.com proxy_pass targetdomain.com proxy_ssl_certificate 3.crt proxy_ssl_certificate_key 3.pem

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name target.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    # ssl_stapling on;
    # ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://targetdomain.com/;
        proxy_ssl_certificate        /home/user/1.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key    /home/user/1.pem;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;
    server_name target2.mydomain.com;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    # ssl_stapling on;
    # ssl_stapling_verify on;
    resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 5s;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains";
    add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://targetdomain.com/;
        proxy_ssl_certificate        /home/user/2.crt;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key    /home/user/2.pem;
        proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
}
```

```
...
```

The problem: on each nginx restart all 3 servers use the same certificate either 1,2 or 3.
Originally a single pfx certificate (for each user) was provided to me for target domain.
Each pfx file was converted to .pem (containing a decrypted private key) and a .crt (pem format) file containing 3 certificate (I don't know why, but it seems to need all 3 of them).

So how can I fix this and make nginx use the proper cert for each server?

Comment: It seems the problem is with the 3 certificates in one file.

The above configuration works properly for another website, where the exported crt (pem) file contains only one certificate

Comment: If you have three certiricates in one crt file, then please add their DN and AltNames fields to your question. The situation when three sites use the same certificate can happen only if the certificate is wildcard `*.mydomain.com` or includes all three target names as AltNames.